# Traefik Reverse Proxy with Letsencrypt Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I bought a domain from Google Domains. I changed the DNS records to cloudflare. I then made an `.htpasswd` file and saved it to `/docker/shared/` I also made a `rules.toml` file located at `/etc/traefik/rules.toml` I placed nothing inside of this file.

I have a file located at `/docker/traefik/traefik.toml` this file has the following in it (I changed EMAIL and DOMAIN to mine):

```
#debug = true

logLevel = "ERROR" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
InsecureSkipVerify = true 
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations 
[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "email@domain.com" #any email id will work
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true 
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "EXAMPLE.COM"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.EXAMPLE.COM"

# Connection to docker host system (docker.sock)
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "EXAMPLE.COM"
watch = true
# This will hide all docker containers that don't have explicitly  
# set label to "enable"
exposedbydefault = false
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    command: --templates http://templates/templates.json
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/portainer/data:/data
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}

  watchtower:
    container_name: watchtower
    restart: always
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --schedule "0 0 4 * * *" --cleanup

  netdata:
    container_name: vigilant_aryabhata
    restart: always
    image: titpetric/netdata
    ports:
      - "19999:19999"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
  traefik:
    hostname: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    networks:
#      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
#      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
      - CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
#      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared

networks:
   traefik_proxy:
     external:
       name: traefik_proxy
   default:
     driver: bridge
```

I then run:

```
docker-compose -f ${USERDIR}/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

And then I run:

```
steve@TeamAmerica-PlexServer:~/docker$ docker-compose logs -tf --tail="50"
```

Which then gives me the following error:

```
traefikAttaching to traefik
traefik       | 2018-07-08T01:15:14.506938691Z time="2018-07-08T01:15:14Z" level=error msg="Error starting provider *file.Provider: error reading configuration file: /etc/traefik/rules.toml - open /etc/traefik/rules.toml: no such file or directory"
```

From here I don't really know what to do.

Comment: /etc/traefik/ is mounted as volume? If you remove your rules.toml from configuration you get the same error?

Comment: I'll comment out the filename and see what happens. It's just odd becuase it most certainly does exist.

Answer (score 0):

> I also made a rules.toml file located at /etc/traefik/rules.toml I placed nothing inside of this file.

In your config you list:

```
[file]
watch = true
filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"
```

Is this located on your machine at: `${USERDIR}/docker/traefik`? So that the container can access it?